# How to get value of any one text box on drop down change

Tags: jquery

I have append a dropdown list and a textbox using jquery, Now I want value of textbox which dropdown list is change using jquery.

```
$(".addtable").click(function () {
    debugger;
    $("#ordertable tbody").append('<tr><td>@(Html.Raw(Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MedID, ViewBag.MedicineList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control nn", placeholder = "Category", id = "manfac", required = "required" }).ToString().Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "")))</td><td><input type="number" class="form-control nn" name="Quantity" required></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
});
```

here is a code to append a dropdown and textbox that's working well..

Comment: you want selected dropdown value in the input ? is this you want

Comment: Will you include your code into a snippet for us so that we can see it working live? It's the 7th button from the left on your editing toolbar.